# Calling Base Constructor from Child Constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

Calling the base constructor from child constructor is a best practice? Here the base is an `abstract class`.

Here is the sample code

```
abstract class MyBase
{
    String l_strChildName;
    public MyBase(String Name)
    {
        l_strChildName = Name;
    }

    public abstract void func();
}

class MyChild_One : MyBase
{
    public MyChild_One() : base("MyChild One") { }

    public override void func()
    {

    }
}

class MyChild_Two : MyBase
{
    public MyChild_Two() : base("MyChild Two") { }

    public override void func()
    {

    }
}
```

Is this calling mechanism is a best practice?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin : I just need to know whether it is recommended practice or not?

Comment: Your question is very broad - if the framework lets you do it, then there's always going to be a situation in which it's appropriate. If your class _needs_ `l_strChildName` to be populated in order to function, and if it's going to have a different value in each derived class, then yes, it's a good idea to call the base constructor, as it guarantees that you can't accidentally leave an important field uninitialised. However, it's probably a good idea to make such a field immutable, via the `readonly` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

The base class should, by design, encapsulate functionality that will be common to all derived classes (since it will be inherited by them). If the field/property that you are initializing through the base class constructor is relevant to the initialization of all derived classes, then yes, passing it to the base class constructor through the `base` keyword is the correct approach.

In your case, since the base class is abstract and its only constructor requires a parameter, then using the `base` keyword actually becomes mandatory; there is no other way of initializing an instance from the class hierarchy.

I am assuming that the example you provided is contrived for the sake of the question. You should *not* hard-code a class name; you may use the `GetType` method (or the `is` keyword) for identifying an instance’s actual type at run-time:

```
MyBase x = new MyChild_One();
Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().Name);   // Outputs "MyChild_One"
```

For fields/properties whose values will never change, you could also use an abstract read-only property that is overridden by all derived classes:

```
abstract class MyBase
{
    public abstract String l_strChildName { get; }
}

class MyChild_One : MyBase
{
    public override String l_strChildName 
    { 
        get { return "MyChild One"; }
    }
}

class MyChild_Two : MyBase
{
    public override String l_strChildName 
    { 
        get { return "MyChild Two"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The intention is not to get the child name, but to initialize some objects in the base (in my project)

Comment: You should have to "taste" the runtime type.if your base class needs knowledge about the run-time type of the object of a derived class there's something fishy about the design.

Comment: @RuneFS: Good point. Initialization that is influenced by the type of the derived class should be implemented in overridden methods (or their derived constructors).

Comment: and it should of course have been "shouldn't have to" :)

Answer (score 1):

Your base class constructor requires a parameter, while the children don't, so I don't see how you could avoid calling the base constructor in this case - it's required

Answer (score 1):

A base constructor of a class will always be called before the class' own constructor is executed. The ":base(*value*)" syntax is just a way of passing parameters to it, if you want to call the default constructor you do not have to write ":base()" it will be called anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's only that one constructor define for the base class one **have** to call it.

If there'd been multiple defined you could choose which one to call.

If the base class has a default constructor you and omit explicitly calling it. Eg.

```
: base()
```

is not required. That however doesn't mean it's not called only that the compiler emits the call without you having to state it explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its fine, if the derived class need the same base class constructor. its better to use **base**
keyword for calling the base class constructor.

Comment: It's not only better it's required in this case